# Setting Up Single Sign On with Active Directory

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, active-directory, single-sign-on

I need help setting up Active Directory with Single Sign On. I think this may be called Kerberos. I have a simple requirement in that I have 3 types of users: guest,operator, and admin. I would life to setup locally first. Right now I have an AD LDS acting like a Windows Server 2008 R2 on Windows 7.

Upon the user logging onto their computer and then running a web app, the system needs to know what kind of user has logged in and what each type/group apps/programs they have access to.

Comment: so... what have you tried so far?

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn so far I just created a local domain controller. I am currently trying to understand how to add users and verify them.

Comment: @LorenzoVonMatterhorn also I am just using a single forest if that helps any.